# Can I separate out part of a question as a new post?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Recently I asked [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61409/crack-the-password) puzzle, for which I will be providing a new hint, but I want to ask the second part

> I am the ONLY one standing between ad23dnd anagrammatically. You have to look for the first half of me

as a separate riddle. 
which was solved partially

> the ONLY one standing between 2d and 3d

But I am not sure, if this will be too broad.
I think this question is awesome by itself, I was pondering about the vagueness/broadness about it. (It can also be used as a hint for the riddle mentioned, though it seems a little far-fetched)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a hint, or new subpuzzle, is **already included** in the text of your original post, then it's **not** a good idea to repost it as a new puzzle. This essentially duplicates content, and as such your new puzzle would be likely to be closed as a duplicate of the original. You could potentially edit it out of the original puzzle before reposting it, but that might confuse people who'd seen it there first, especially if there are already comments/answers on the original reacting to that part specifically.

If you're thinking of adding **a *new* hint/subpuzzle** which isn't already there, then you **can** post it as a new puzzle instead of editing it into the original -- **provided that it can stand alone as a self-contained puzzle**. It's a long-established (occasional) practice on this site to post new puzzles which are valid puzzles in their own right but *also* hints to harder existing puzzles. I recall AE doing it back in the spaghetti days, with [Decode the message enciphered in these symbols: ◳◰ ◓◨ ◨◧◕ ◎◌ ◱◯◱◯ ◍◌○ ◉◉ ◇◔◓◕ ◐►◓◒ ◒◑ ◈◑ ◆◆◓ ◉◉◉](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4642/5373) and [Decode the message enciphered in these symbols: ↗↑↙↓↘←↑↙↘↘↗↓↗←↙↓↖](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4735/5373) posted as hints to [The Security to the Party [12] (now with party soundtrack!)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4057/5373), and I've also done it recently myself, posting [My first is in the kill zone, but not in no man's land](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61639/5373) as a hint to [Strange sorceresses swallow scarlet swedes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61551/5373) and [We're found in vans, in bags, on bikes - we're found in books, in maps, online](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61976/5373) as a hint to [Who are these two sisters?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61740/5373)

Comment: Thank you, I will update my question, and add the new hint as new question

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would want to do this.

It's already been asked as part of your other puzzle; generally, trying to take a piece of an existing puzzle and asking it anew as a new question just ends up being closed as duplicate, because ... well ... it basically is.
The mini-riddle, absent any other context, would seem to me to be too vague and too underspecified to be answerable on its own with any degree of confidence in the correctness of the answer.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you